# How to make a local variable in Plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, grouping

I want to simplify my code below by creating a local variable as a temporary container to save the value of `\numexpr#1+#2+#3+#4+#5}`.

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames,rgb,table]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=20mm,vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{%
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=Red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=3pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=Blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=Green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}



\makeatletter
\newcommand\ratio[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1pt/#2\relax}
\makeatother



\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\arrayrulecolor{Red}


\newcounter{No}
\renewcommand{\theNo}{\arabic{No}}


\newcolumntype{S}[1]%
{%
    >{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  c%
  <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
}%
\newcolumntype{O}[1]%
{%
    >{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  c%
  <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
}%
\newcolumntype{I}[1]%
{%
    >{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}\vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  c%
  <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
}%


\newenvironment{InlineTable}[5][0]%
{%    
    \setcounter{No}{0}%
    \newcount\ITT
    \ITT\numexpr#1+#2+#3+#4+#5\relax
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
            |>{\stepcounter{No}\centering\scriptsize\theNo}O{\ratio{#2}{\ITT}}<{}%
            |>{\centering}I{\ratio{#3}{\ITT}}<{\input{\jobname.tmp}}%
            |>{\centering\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}I{\ratio{#4}{\ITT}}<{}%
            |>{\scriptsize}O{\ratio{#5}{\ITT}}<{}%
            |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}%
}


\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{&&&#1\tabularnewline\hline}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language={PSTricks},
alsolanguage={[LaTeX]TeX},
breaklines=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}%
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\def\MyRow{%        
        \VerbatimEnvironment%
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}

\def\endMyRow{%
        \end{VerbatimOut}%      
}




\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
%Landscape starts here.
\begin{landscape}

\begin{InlineTable}[10]{5}{25}{30}{40}%
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture*[showgrid](3,3)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pnode(3,3){B}
\ncline{A}{B}
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[1]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[2]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[3]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Yellow](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{%
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\end{equation}
is the fundamental theorem of calculus.
}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Maroon!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{%
Today I ate burnt bread. It was so delicious.
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\end{equation}
is the fundamental theorem of calculus.
}
%=============
\end{InlineTable}
\end{landscape}
%Landscape stops here.
\pagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite apart from my answer to the question, I don't think this is going to work as `\stepcounter` is not expandable. Table header material needs to be expanded to set up the underlying `\halign`.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with plain TeX.

Comment: Please try and post _minimal_ examples that focus on the question you have. Your code here is _far_ too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX environments form groups, and so any variable you set within it will be local unless you use `\global`. Now, LaTeX counters are set globally, so you'll need a TeX count:

```
\newcount\mycount
...
\newenvironment{InlineTable}[5][0]%
{%
  \mycount\numexpr#1+#2+#3+#4+#5\relax
...
```

Comment: Can I put `\newcount\mycount` as a local variable inside the environment definition above?

Comment: @xport. Ah, you are thinking of 'local to a function'. TeX does not work like that: things are local to TeX groups. You can of course put `\newcount\mycount` inside the definition, but the new count is allocated globally. This makes life a little complicated, and I would recommend not doing it. (There have been various discussions on locally-allocated variables recently. The problem is that as TeX doesn't have functions, but has macros, the 'localness' is not so easy to track in a general sense. Perhaps take a look at the etex package for local allocation of count variables.)

Comment: I think I might write something for my blog (http://www.texdev.net/) about local variables.

Comment: macros are local, but registers (counts, lengths, boxes, etc.) are global.

Comment: @Leo. Not quite. By convention, registers are _allocated_ globally, although they can be assigned locally. It's quite possible to do a local allocation of registers: see the `etex` package for one approach. The problem is that 'local' here is somewhat different to other languages, and this leads to a situation where local allocation does not necessarily translate into 'a good idea'.